# How to query random document, which does not exists in another collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of Cars and collection BookedCars.
I want to random query N cars that are not in BookedCars.

Field matching can be done by Cars.carRegisteration and BookedCars.carRegisteration.

Is that possible using `{ $sample: { size: 1 } }` and maybe some lookup ?

Thanks

Comment: How are cars and booked cars linked?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor by Cars.carRegisteration and BookedCars.carRegisteration

Comment: You can simply check for cars, for which the carRegistration key doesn't exists.